# Apache2 reverse proxy with response caching

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, cache, mod-proxy, memcached

I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy for an application running on a local port. I want to cache responses from this application in memory. So requesting the same URL frequently should give me cached responses from Apache, not fresh responses from the application itself. Note: these are dynamic responses to GET requests, *not* static files. I read the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html) and decided to go with Memcached.

Here's my configuration:

```
CacheEnable socache /
CacheSocache memcache:localhost:11211
CacheHeader on
CacheDefaultExpire 86400
CacheMaxExpire 604800

ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:2322/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:2322/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://my.domain.com/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

**Somehow, absolutely nothing is being stored in Memcached** when I check the stats. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** also tried `CacheEnable socache http://localhost:2322/` without success.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this isn't something that can (or should) be done in Apache itself. A dedicated cacher/load balancer like [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/intro/) should be used instead.